# SimpleEmail works within IntelliJ fails from command line

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, gmail

Using org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail to send an email from within a background application. This has been working for 8 months with no problems. On January 1st it started failing. The application is Scala (2.12.8) and Java (1.8) running on a Mac (macOS 10.15.7).

Sending the email to smtp.googlemail.com port 465 (also tried smtp.gmail.com).

Using IntelliJ as the IDE. If the application runs *within* IntelliJ, it still works perfectly, but if you create a Jar and run from the command line it fails every time. Running from a Jar using 'sudo' also fails.

So did some setting change at Google as of Jan 1? Why would it still work within the IDE - is there a context or certificate present within IntelliJ? A certificate needed for SSL?

Appreciate any suggestions!

-------- Addendum - all parameters to the send() method ---------

```
       Heading: FAILURE       --- my addition
            ID: (None)        --- my addition
            To: j.crowley@computer.org
       Subject: Backup for JDCMacBook was 150.1M
       Message: For JDCMacBook, Drive: USBExtA, Backup 2021-01-08-103310 compared to 2021-01-08-053055 Adds: 3.3M  Changes: 142.3M Deletes: 4.4M 
SendIfPossible: true
       To Host: smtp.googlemail.com
       To Port: 465
     Auth User: tmviewer.smtp@gmail.com
      Auth Pwd: .... redacted ....
       Set SSL: true

------- Stack trace -----------

     Exception: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com:465


10:44:11.749  0:00.002 ERROR: org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1469)

10:44:11.749           ERROR: org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1496)

10:44:11.749           ERROR: jdctm.Utils$.sendEMail(Utils.scala:547)

10:44:11.750  0:00.001 ERROR: jdctm.NotifyInfo.notify(Cache.scala:1036)

10:44:11.750           ERROR: jdctm.Cache$.notify(Cache.scala:722)

10:44:11.750           ERROR: jdctm.ExecuteTMUtil.run(Cache.scala:952)

10:44:11.750           ERROR: java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)

10:44:11.751  0:00.001 ERROR: java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)

10:44:11.751           ERROR: java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: How does it fails? Which error do you get?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace error maybe? Could also be something else that has changed on your local machine that is causing the problem (seeing as the IDE is somewhat more static).

Comment: Added parameters and stack trace to the original.

Comment: A long shot: could it be that there is a firewall rule preventing the command line application from working and that IntelliJ has all needed rights? No clue how this works on Mac, but this can happen on Windows I know.

Comment: @Fullslack - excellent thought, and should have thought of it myself! But unfortunately from the command line can 'ping' to smtp.googlemail.com and 'telnet' to port 465, so we are getting through the network to the server. Wondering if there is an SSL certificate somewhere that expired at the end of 2020 ... but don't know where it might be.

Comment: Could try https://support.google.com/a/answer/6180220?hl=en, or search for `smtp.googlemail.com ssl certificate`. Still weird though, you expect IntelliJ to use the system certificate store and not their own. *Edit:* I stand corrected, they appear to use their own https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/Trusted-SSL-Certificates.html

Comment: Are you really using the Unix `sendmail` program as you tagged it?

Comment: Why not keep using Java 15? Might help with the transition to 16, that's also quite a big step. Using 15 might so errors you can fix now, instead of waiting till 16 is released. Glad you figured it out, even though it wasn't mentioned in the original question.

Comment: If your comment is really an answer, you need to post it as an answer and not here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ is using Java 8, had upgraded to Java 16 (early access) for some tests and that is what is used on the command line. Turned on SimpleEmail setDebug(true) and failing during the SSL handshake - No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate) So some change in protocols/cipher suites between Java 8 and 16 (ea). WORKs under Java 15.0.1, FAILs under jdk16.ea.30.2130. Will revert to Java 8 for now, retest once Java 16 is released.